# Stored proc + variable contains table row field

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to do query on table where a field's text is contained in a variable.

Example:

**Table A**

```
ID     Ref               Processed
----|-----------------|---------
1   |  I want a pool  |   0
2   |  I want a bike  |   0
```

**Table B**

```
ID     Text
----|---------------
1   |  pool
2   |  bike
```

Get all unprocessed rows from `TableA` into `#tempTable`

```
select * into #tmpTable from TableA where processed = 0
```

I then cycle over each row in `#tmpTable` and set `@Variable` to the current field `Ref`.

So the first time through `@Variable = 'I want a pool'` and then `@Variable = 'I want a bike'`.

I then need to query `TableB` where the `Text` field is contained inside `@Variable` and select the row.

I know the following doesn't work, but it's where I need to end up:

```
select * from TableB where @Variable LIKE '% '+Text+' %'
```

I'm editing an existing stored procedure so if there's a better way to go about this then I'm open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select a.*, b.text
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a.processed = 0 and
        ref like '%'+b.text+'%';
```

EDIT:

If you want to match words that are separated by spaces:

```
     on a.processed = 0 and
        ' '+ref+' ' like '% '+b.text+' %';
```

Comment: Was going about it the wrong way. On a different note, if I use '% '+Text+' %' instead of '%'+Text+'%' will that return rows that contain the full word and not partial words?

Comment: The expression `'%'+b.txt+'%'` will only match the full word of whatever is in `text`.

Comment: So what would the expression be for matching the whole word. E.g POOL but not CARPOOL? Taking into account start and end of lines?